# asp.net WebForm or MVC browser game

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I would like to know is this platfoerm (MVC or WebForms) good technology of creating webBrowser based games and if so maybe You have got some tutorials, books, any resources which may be helpfull in beggining with such things.

thanks for help, bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither are platforms on which you can really develop games. You should look ideally at [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/) or [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/).

Other than that, I would suggest using WebForms as you will have the advantage of ViewState to play with and a pseudo-event-driven engine. MVC might be a little more hard work but if you're confortable with native web development you may prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

Flash is one of the most established platforms for creating web games and I'll advice you to use it for almost any kind of game. If you are familiar with the .net technology stack you can try Silverlight. It is also very powerful and also support some good 3D features. If you are in a mood for exploring try the html 5 + JavaScript but be aware that it is not fully supported by all browsers. A good article for game development with JS and html 5 is http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/38364.aspx . The only type of games I thing asp.net and MVC are suitable for is the turn based (text based) online strategies like [Utopia](http://utopia-game.com/) and [Dominion](http://www.kamikazegames.com/dominion/). In that case I'll strongly suggest ASP.NET MVC framework as it has a lot of capabilities that you'll find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't disagree with these answers, but I'd like to offer an alternative viewpoint, based on the type of game you're making. If you are looking at creating something very simple with little or no graphics, ASP.NET is certainly a viable solution. Some extremely nice games have been done with seemingly "non-gaming" languages ... look at Kingdom of Loathing (written in PHP).

As far as webforms vs. MVC, I would answer that question the same I always think it should it be answered: what will MVC provide that your app needs (or may need in the future) that makes the additional learning curve worth it? If you're already familiar with webforms and don't think (really, REALLY don't think) that you'll need MVC, I say save the development time and use it.